# How to convert day of week name to day of week number

Tags: javascript

How can I get the integer equivalent of days of the week i.e `monday` to `2`, `tuesday` to `3`, `wednesday` to `4`, etc?

Here is what I have:

```
var days  = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
```

and i need to do

```
console.log(days['monday']) //i need to see the integer 2
console.log(days['tuesday']) //i need to see the integer 3
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of an input and an example of your desired output?  For example:  input: bar = new Date("2014 May 13"); foo = dayOfWeekNumber(bar);  expected output: foo = 2;
Also, please provide a full code snippet of what you've written thus far.  As it is, it looks like you're just asking people to write code for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can use a lookup object:

```
var days = {
    sunday: 1,
    monday: 2,
    tuesday: 3,
    wednesday: 4,
    thursday: 5,
    friday: 6,
    saturday: 7
}

console.log(days["sunday"]) //1
```

Now, simply access any of the above properties and it's value will be the numeric day of the week!

```
console.log(days["monday"]) //2
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the "indexOf" function of javascript.

```
var days  = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];

console.log(days.indexOf('Sunday')); // return 0
console.log(days.indexOf('Tuesday')); // return 2
```

But remember that "indexOf" is case sensitive and that it will return "-1", if the string is not in the array.

Comment: Note that this is not supported in IE7 or IE8, but can be worked around with [this polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Polyfill). [tymeJV's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23640567/how-to-convert-day-of-week-name-to-day-of-week-number/23640598#23640598) does *not* have this limitation.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, for something like this, you'll likely want to create a function so you don't have to repeat yourself (see [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)). Here's a sample function, that also [converts the incoming week day string to lowercase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) so "Wednesday" will return the same result as "wednesday".

## Code ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bfrohs/7WSAF/))

*Note: Comment block with function documentation is using style recommended by [JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org/index.html).*

```
/**
 * @param {String} weekDay
 * @returns {Number} Day of week weekDay is. Returns `undefined` for invalid weekDay.
 */
function getWeekDayNumber(weekDay) {
    var days = {
        sunday: 1,
        monday: 2,
        tuesday: 3,
        wednesday: 4,
        thursday: 5,
        friday: 6,
        saturday: 7
    };

    return days[weekDay.toLowerCase()];
}
```

```
var day = getWeekDayNumber("Sunday"); // `day` now equals `1`
```